# how access data during intermediate transformation steps before final data table (i.e. need a column before it is pivoted)

Tags: ironpython, spotfire, tibco

Table1 is loaded as a data source, then undergoes some transformations (replace columns, join columns, etc.) from other tables and then outputs Table1Final.

One of the transformations pivots ColumnA so if five unique values are in ColumnA then the Table1Final would no longer have ColumnA but instead would have 5 new columns based on the old ColumnA's values.

What I need to do is access that ColumnA before it is pivoted into multiple columns. Ultimately, I want to get the unique values from ColumnA to populate a document property.

I've tried a data function transformation but that just modifies the data in-place (was hoping I could output a duplicate table or similar approach but it changes the table in-place so that does not work). I have been able to see the operations and transformation types in IronPython but can't quite figure out how to get the values before/after a specific transformation step, if possible.